# Including end mark in definitions and examples (using amsthm)

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I am using the `amsthm` package, and I have this in the preamble:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
```

(I use only one counter for all environments -- this is intentional)

Now, I'd like the `example` environment to actually have an end mark similar to proofs (but with a different symbol). (Maybe also for the `definition` environment)

The `\newtheoremstyle` command from amsthm doesn't seem to help.

Is there some easy way to do this, or should I just define new LaTeX environments (with `\newenvironment`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `thmtools` package as a front-end to `amsthm`; adding the end marks is then an easy matter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[style=definition,qed=$\blacksquare$,numberwithin=chapter]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=definition,qed=$\blacktriangle$,sibling=definition]{example}

\declaretheorem[style=plain,sibling=definition]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,sibling=definition]{lemma}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{definition}
Test
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
Test
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]